# Docker Compose, mapped port is unreachable, Time Wait

Tags: windows, docker-compose, tcp

So, I have a Docker Compose build with two containers. Run it on Windows.

- One container contains a postgres DB, it has it's port mapped to the host machine and everything works properly.
- Another one contains FastAPI server and also has a mapped port. But I can't reach it from the host machine.

I know for sure, that server is running fine, I see logs, I can go into the container and check it with curl:

```
# curl 127.0.0.1:8000
{"detail":"Not Found"}
```

That's a default answear from FastAPI, so server is fine.

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  api_service:
    build: ./api_service/
    volumes:
      - ./api_service/app:/app/app
    ports:
      - 5003:8000
    depends_on:
      - api_db
    env_file:
      - config.env
      - api_db_config.env    
  
  api_db:
    image: postgres
    ports:  # for debug purpuses
      - 5005:5432
    volumes:
      - ./api_db/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./api_db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    env_file:
      - api_db_config.env
```

I thought that maybe, a host port is occupied, so I checked ports with TCPView.
[image: TCPView while server is idle]
Here I can see both host ports occupied by three process each, that's OK. But when I try to reach backend (5003) from browser, I see this:
[image: Time wait on TCPView]

It seems, that for some reason, port can not accept connection, but I have no clue why and how can I fix it. Any help would be apprecietad.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an exact reason for such behaviour, but I've managed to fix it. In my run.sh script i started uvicorn as

```
uvicorn app.main:app --reload
```

I made it work by adding key `--host 0.0.0.0`